# Allow only one document to be created in Firestore, disallow update, edit etc

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing Quiz app of sorts using VueJS and Firebase firestore.

So far I've made everything except this one last part.

Users are allowed to answer questions without being logged in.

And at the final stage, there is one last question. Everyone can answer this question, but I need to be able to detect who is first.

So far I've tried with checking if answers collection is empty, this works, but response time is the issue and I can reproduce easily two or more users answering at the same time and having message they are the winners.

I'm currently trying with transactions, but cannot figure it out how to catch if document already exists. Here's the sample code:

```
let vm = this;
fsdb.runTransaction(function (transaction) {
    let voteDocRef = fsdb.collection('final_vote').doc('vote');
    return transaction.get(voteDocRef).then(function (voteDoc) {
        if (!voteDoc.exists) {
            voteDocRef.set({voted: true}).then(function () {
                vm.trueAnswer(index);
                return 'set executed!';
            }).catch(function () {
                vm.falseAnswer(index);
                throw 'Someone already voted!';
            });
            return 'Document created!';
        } else {
            throw 'Someone already voted!';
        }
    });
```

vm.trueAnswer and vm.falseAnswer are the methods I'm using to show the popup message.

And this is the method that's triggered once the user submits the answer.

At first I've tried with rules that everyone can read, write ... but now I'm trying to limit write only if document doesn't exist. Here's the current rule set:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /{collectionName}/{docId} {
      allow create: if collectionName == 'final_vote' && docId == 'vote';
    }
  }
}
```

So far this doesn't work as expected.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try the following code?

```
let vm = this;
fsdb.runTransaction(function (transaction) {
    let voteDocRef = fsdb.collection('final_vote').doc('vote');
    return transaction.get(voteDocRef).then(function (voteDoc) {
        if (voteDoc.data().voted !== true) {
            voteDocRef.set({voted: true}).then(function () {
                vm.trueAnswer(index);
                return 'set executed!';
            }).catch(function () {
                vm.falseAnswer(index);
                throw 'Someone already voted!';
            });
            return 'Document created!';
        } else {
            throw 'Someone already voted!';
        }
    });
```

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /final_vote/{docId} {
      allow create, update: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I think that `final_votes` is better than `final_vote` as collection name.